# Master theorem - second case issue

Tags: data-structures, complexity-theory, master-theorem

Given the following recursive equations:

```
T(n) = 5T(n/5)+(5sin^5(5n^5)+5)*n
T(n) = T(n/4)+2sin^2(n^4)
```

I can easily see that both equations fit the 2nd case of the master theorem,

but due to the fact that sin is a circular function, it seems that a large enough N 
might bring it really close to zero.
So, we will always be able to find an N > N0 for two constants c1,c2 (By theta definition)
which will disapprove it..

Is it really possible solving it with the master theorem?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think you're right, the Master Theorem does not apply here. The reason for this is that the difference between `f(n)` and `n^(log_b(a))` has to be polynomial. (See [Master Theorem Recurrences: What is exactly polynomial difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669490/master-theorem-recurrences-what-is-exactly-polynomial-difference))

In your case:
`((5sin^5(5n^5)+5)*n)/(n^(log_5(5)))=(5sin^5(5n^5)+5`and
`(2sin^2(n^4))/(n^(log_4(1)))= 2sin^2(n^4)`, which is not polynomial, so Master Theorem is invalid in this case.